# React: how can I process the data I get from an API before I render it out?

Tags: reactjs, api

I have no issues fetching the data from an API using useEffect. That works fine.

The problem is that I need to apply some processing to the data before I actually render it out (in this case, I need to shuffle the array that I receive).

I tried a million different ways, but I just can't find the right place to write that logic. Basically, it won't work anywhere.

What is the right way of going about this?

Comment: use `console.log`

Comment: https://medium.com/@felippenardi/how-to-do-componentdidmount-with-react-hooks-553ba39d1571 , you should call it like this useEffect(() => {}, []), it will be working same way as componentDidMount. Don't pass any params to []

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do everything with data before setState.
is useEffect when you fetched data from Api, shuffle it and then do setState.

little example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  axios.get("http://example.com/data").then(response => {
    const data = shuffle(response.data);
    setState(data);
  })
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but where do I write the shuffle function? By the way, I guess "response.data" would be the argument for that shuffle function, right?

Comment: yes, right. and location of shuffle function is not matter.
you can write that before useEffect. shuffle function just get data and do shuffle and return it back

Comment: I wrote the function inside useEffect, right after the API call and it worked great. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      await axios.get("http://example.com/data").then(response => {
         const data = shuffle(response.data);
         setState(data);
      });
    };

    fetchData();

    return () => {
      // Clean up func
    }
}, []); //[] will prevent infinite API calling.
```